# iOS 10 Messages sending the incorrect music track

Tags: ios, messages, apple-music

Me and my friend just updated to iOS 10. I've sent him a music track via iMessage.  He says that the sent track is a different track from the same artist.

When I tap the `Play` button to play the track within Messages, it's the track I've selected, but when I tap the album, it takes me to Apple Music with the incorrect track selected (and my friend sees that incorrect track). This seems to be a very serious issue, how do I get rid of it? (and can someone please add the tag `ios10`?)

Comment: If you're sure you tapped the correct song and even tried this multiple times with different artists and different songs, then you should contact Apple Support: https://getsupport.apple.com/.

Comment: @fbara I've tried with one song but I'm sure it's not my mistake. The track name displayed in Messages is different from the one that plays, but those same tracks play correctly under their correct names in Music. It displays one track name, but opens another track when tapped anyway. it's clearly a bug. Even if I mistakenly added a track with an incorrect name (and I haven't. Double checked.) it should obviously display a consistent name at Messages and in Music.